# Как в PHP получить браузер пользователя?

Tags: php

Я пытаюсь получить браузер пользователя с помощью  `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`
Но когда я , например захожу с помощью chrome , то эта переменная содержит
`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.79 Safari/537.36` 
Как корректно получить браузер пользователя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся проблема в том, что браузер определяется неточно. К примеру, на [моем сайте](https://progh.info) с браузером Opera пишет вот что:

[image]

Поэтому лучше тестировать браузер через JavaScript вот так:

```
//Создаем объект 'user', который будет содержать информацию Detect.js 
//Вызываем detect.parse() с navigator.userAgent в качестве аргумента
var user = detect.parse(navigator.userAgent);

// Выводим нужные значения в консоли браузера
console.log(
  user.browser.family
  user.browser.version
  user.os.name
)
```

Кстати, такой способ освобождает вас от того, чтобы разбирать длиннюююющую строку :)

P. S. Вся эта бухта-барахта происходит из-за того, что часто один браузер основан на другом, или же они используют один и тот же движок.